# Opening my entire directories(browser folder) in winSCP?

Tags: sublimetext3, directory, winscp

I'm using Sublime Text 3 as my editor in winSCP. How can i open the entire directories from Sublime Text 3 in winSCP ?

Comment: What does it mean "open the entire directories from Sublime Text 3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that the files and folders appear in the sidebar but i think i found a answer for my question, namely i have to stall samba on my Linux Server or to install addon (SFTP) on Sublime Text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the 'SFTP' package in Sublime, create a sftp-config file to connect to your server and sync a remote directory to a local directory.

- Install SFTP for sublime:
  https://codexns.io/products/sftp_for_sublime/install
- Sync: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6NqBGHFfm0

If you don't want to sync the folders you can just right click on your sftp-config `file->SFTP/FTP->Download Folder`.

More details about sftp-config here: https://codexns.io/products/sftp_for_sublime/settings

It seems a bug in Sublime is that if Sublime is not the highlighted app while downloading it may cause problems.